# How to slice index with user input (Python Tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter, indexing, slice

I want it to slice index with user input. For example, entrybox1 = 0, entrybox2= 10

**Without user input, it worked like this**

```
file_data["data1"] = content[10:20]
```

**I tried to "get" the entry boxes value, but it failed , nothing is showing up.**

```
file_data[key1EntryName.get()] = content[key1EntryStartIndex.get():key1EntryEndIndex.get()]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem might be that you don't convert them to integers:

```
file_data[key1EntryName.get()] = content[
int(key1EntryStartIndex.get()):int(key1EntryEndIndex.get())]
```

Comment: where should i add the integers  ? after `content` ?

Comment: `content[int(key1EntryStartIndex.get()):int(key1EntryEndIndex.get())]` i tried with this, but its still not working

Comment: Maybe there isn't anything inside the entries. Do you get errors?

Comment: After i pasting ur code it worked now . urs is just the same with my code but mine couldn't worked lol hahah, weird

Answer (score 0):

input() creates strings which cannot be used to slice.  You have to convert them to integers:

```
startIndex = int(input())
endIndex = int(input())
content = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
file_data = {}
file_data['data'] = content[startIndex:endIndex]
file_data['data']
'fghij'
```

And of course users don't always follow instructions so you should wrap it in a try/except looking for ValueError.